# Is online lottery legal in India?

Tags: criminal-law, india, indian-penal-code, indian-constitutional-law, lotteries

Is a person from Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India allowed to play an online lottery? I know playing the lottery is banned in Uttar Pradesh, India, but what about playing the online lottery of other states or playing the international lottery.
For example Powerball, Mega million from lotto247.com

I have read many answers online but none of them had a source. Some say no and some say yes it is allowed. Please help me read trustworthy, legitimate material that can certify whether it is really allowed or not.

Answer (score 3):

Section 3(a) of the *Uttar Pradesh Unauthorised Lottery (Prevention) Act of 1995* states that..

> No personal shall promote or conduct **any lottery**...

No distinction is made in the Act between physical and on-line lotteries, but whether this law is actually enforceable for using non-jurisdictional websites will depend on the circumstances and available evidence - which is another (and potentially off topic) question.

https://www.latestlaws.com/bare-acts/state-acts-rules/state-laws/uttar-pradesh-unauthorised-lottery-prevention-act-1995/

Comment: While I agree with what you said, I'm not sure the wording of the act includes participating in a lottery (it explicitly mentions running or promoting one). E.g. it mentions selling tickets as an offense, but not buying.